# Unexpectedly unwrapping an optional to find a nil after an API call to Spotify

Tags: swift, api, spotify

So I know this may be a bit specific but I've been staring at my code and am unable to resolve this issue. Basically, I'm making a network call to spotify to obtain a certain playlist and pass a number that will ultimately determine the number of songs I get back. The code is basically as follows:

```
    // A network call is made just above to return somePlaylist
    let playlist = somePlaylist as! SPTPartialPlaylist    
    var songs: [SPTPartialTrack] = []

    // load in playlist to receive back songs
    SPTPlaylistSnapshot.playlistWithURI(playlist.uri, session: someSession) { (error: NSError!, data: AnyObject!) in

        // cast the data into a correct format
        let playlistViewer = data as! SPTPlaylistSnapshot
        let playlist = playlistViewer.firstTrackPage

        // get the songs
        for _ in 1...numberOfSongs {
            let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(playlist.items.count)))
            songs.append(playlist.items[random] as! SPTPartialTrack)
        }
    }
```

The problem comes at the portion of code that initializes random. In maybe 1 in 20 calls to this function I, for whatever, reason unwrap a nil value for playlist.items.count and can't seem to figure out why. Maybe it's something I don't understand about API calls or something else I'm failing to see but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Anyone have any recommendations on addressing this issue or how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after sleeping on it and working on it some more I seem to have resolved the issue. Here's the error handling I implemented into my code.

```
if let actualPlaylist = playlist, actualItems = actualPlaylist.items {
        if actualItems.count == 0 {
            SongScraper.playlistHasSongs = false
            print("Empty playlist, loading another playlist")
            return
            }

        for _ in 1...numberOfSongs {
            let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(actualItems.count)))
            songs.append(actualPlaylist.items[random] as! SPTPartialTrack)
        }

        completionHandler(songs: songs)
    }
    else {
        print("Returned a nil playlist, loading another playlist")
        SongScraper.playlistHasSongs = false
        return
    }
```